# The circle is not alignining in the middle

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to align the circle in the middle of the screen but for some reason it stays on the left side only no matter what alignment I use

```
Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
           ) {
            //Align this circle in the middle of the screen
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(200.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ){
                Text(text = "1000 Rs Remaining")
            }
            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowRight, contentDescription = null)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to have the explain why you have your parent view as row.
While the alight it about grouping alignment (horizontalArrangement, verticalAlignment).

Here my solution which seem match your use case.

```
ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Red),
        ) {
            val (circleBox, actionButton) = createRefs()
            IconButton(
                onClick = {

                }, modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(actionButton) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowRight,
                    contentDescription = null)
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(200.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .constrainAs(
                        circleBox
                    ) {
                        centerTo(parent)
                    },
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(text = "1000 Rs Remaining")
            }
        }
```

Here is a render result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two widget in the row, using   `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween` will put the circle in left and icon button in right

You can add `Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))` to make the widgets 3 so the circle can be centered in the middle

```
Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
       ) {

         Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f)),
        //Align this circle in the middle of the screen
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .background(Color.Blue)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ){
            Text(text = "1000 Rs Remaining")
        }
        IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowRight, contentDescription = null)
        }
    }
```